# Exception on Spring Boot startup

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot endpoint which takes inputs from user in Http request body of a POST request and persists it into a  MySql database.

Build is successful but when i try to run the application using the command : 
`mvn spring-boot:run`

It throws an exception and the application doesn't starts.

I am new on spring boot and didn't find about this exception so not many things I have tried to solve this issue. Still waiting for a lead or direction.

Here is the log file on server startup  : 
Have removed few of irrelevant logs to stay within character limits :

> 2019-07-23 16:24:23.121 ERROR 8808 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.defaultViewResolver
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:261) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:170) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:145) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:46) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               ... 23 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfigurationSource
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               ... 45 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               ... 60 common frames omitted
>       2019-07-23 16:24:23.261  WARN 8808 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter$FaviconConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@1e48e3c]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at com.volantis.LoginApplication.main(LoginApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfigurationSource
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>               ... 27 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>               ... 42 common frames omitted
>       [WARNING]
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.defaultViewResolver
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches (SpringBootCondition.java:59)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip (ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
>           at com.volantis.LoginApplication.main (LoginApplication.java:15)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter$FaviconConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@1e48e3c]
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:507)
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:404)
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:389)
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:447)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent (ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition (BeanTypeRegistry.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition (BeanTypeRegistry.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType (BeanTypeRegistry.java:150)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary (BeanTypeRegistry.java:138)
>           at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining (Iterator.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary (BeanTypeRegistry.java:133)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType (BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:268)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:261)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:250)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans (OnBeanCondition.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome (OnBeanCondition.java:145)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches (SpringBootCondition.java:46)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip (ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
>           at com.volantis.LoginApplication.main (LoginApplication.java:15)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfigurationSource
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:763)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition (BeanTypeRegistry.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition (BeanTypeRegistry.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition (BeanTypeRegistry.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType (BeanTypeRegistry.java:150)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary (BeanTypeRegistry.java:138)
>           at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining (Iterator.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary (BeanTypeRegistry.java:133)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType (BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:268)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:261)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType (OnBeanCondition.java:250)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans (OnBeanCondition.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome (OnBeanCondition.java:145)
>           at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches (SpringBootCondition.java:46)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip (ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
>           at com.volantis.LoginApplication.main (LoginApplication.java:15)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] Total time:  9.554 s
>       [INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-23T16:24:24+05:30
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project login: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.defaultViewResolver: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter$FaviconConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@1e48e3c]: org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfigurationSource: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR]
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR]
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

Since the build is passing and the configuration looks fine the application should have started without any exceptions.

Below is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>com.volantis</groupId>
    <artifactId>todo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>login</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>login</name>
<description>Module to cover user registration and login</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show the dependencies

Comment: @Deadpool
I have updated the question with my pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

There was a duplicate jar file in classpath.
There were two spring-web jar in classpath i.e different versions.
I deleted one of the versions and my application is running absolutely fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<parent> ... </parent>` with below code snippet and try.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: This is a child module. Parent module as mentioned in pom is todo. POM for todo has spring-boot-starter-parent. Does it need to be included in child module as well?

Comment: Tried the approach suggested it doesn't seems to work